# How do I add new user accounts with SSH access to my Amazon EC2 Linux instance?

Tags: unix, ssh, amazon-ec2, centos, ssh-keys

I'm trying to access new user which is created in AWS instance using SSH, but it throws an error when i execute the command **ssh -i new_keypair.pem new_user@54.XXX.XXX.XXX**

**Error : Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).**.

I followed each and every steps as mentioned in AWS document **https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/new-user-accounts-linux-instance/**

Please Let me know is there any additional configurations are required to access newly added user using SSH..

Comment: Try adding sudo before firing this command

Comment: @dinesh But when i trying to access old_user with new_keypairs, it's working fine.

Note : i don't have sudo success

Comment: @VenkateshKuppusamy which linux flavour are u using?

Comment: @Dinesh K centos

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/managing-users.html

Comment: Dinesh, I tried above link as well..? Any other suggestions..?

Answer (score 3):

Add the newly created user in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` as mentioned below. It's also working fine.

`AllowUsers root new_user`

`AllowGroups root new_user`

Comment: Please note :  AllowUsers -- This keyword can be followed by a list of user name patterns, separated by spaces.  If specified, login is allowed only for user names that match one of the patterns. 
And that the allow/deny directives are processed in the following order: DenyUsers, AllowUsers, DenyGroups, and finally AllowGroups.

Answer (score 1):

SSH to your EC2 Instance as standard ec2-user

```
sudo adduser -m testuser
sudo su - testuser
mkdir .ssh
chmod 700 .ssh
touch .ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys
```

On your local pc, if you don't have them already, generate rsa keys (always give enter on default options)

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Copy the output (something like this)

> ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDTvTnCzaaIPChWXgvxlyswcNzzTjlYUcfNExm6zGGJRtEcjvHMpV6vg9XMOb9ZgRNhgpWQqitQ9yLy+mjznDerfuK9RsEIdu5wb7uVFXs6TGHy8b9sqid0PH6PYuWiZ1/pA6cRrtQudeqlZuVV5wyimPFKZONW3v+BOp+AtIvChPhZI+rWn0T3vxi2NTHfdqW93VqsQ7ReEkzd1RGxJZ+1X0kADmCJKjwAoju0DvvVz3/xdsc2UT3rjRsUTxDR1bH4GBQr7U1pwCGAqZqvEl72TLpUdWRECG42qIPsut95c237gtzkwlU7iAOeiPWJduMV/bPxXnrB/YqF+XwRMuiz testuser@testEC2

and paste into the .ssh/authorized_keys of your testuser of testinstance (using vi or nano or whatever)

from your client ssh to your ec2

```
ssh testuser@ip.e.c.2
```

This will work. I don't really get the Amazon way of sharing and setting up pem keys. I think it is easier for their automated systems but not for sysadmins. You can use your public key that way on all the servers you need to admin.

Comment: -m is not needed. Please remove it.

Comment: @SmallChess as a home dir is necessary to add .ssh directory and files, I think it's ok to create it with explicit -m